# How to make a photo and save it to an image holder

Tags: java, android, image, android-intent, camera

I need to make a photo and save it to an image holder. Consider a blank activity with 1 button and 1 placeholder. I need the camera program to run and save it to the placeholder. Tried several samples i could actually understand but none works, i get null pointer when assigning to the placeholder. This is my activity so far:

```
public class MarkerInfo extends AppCompatActivity {
    int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;
    public static int count = 0;
    Uri outputFileUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_marker_info);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        final String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/picFolder/";
        File newdir = new File(dir);
        newdir.mkdirs();
        Button capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CameraButton);
        capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // here,counter will be incremented each time,and the picture taken by camera will be stored as 1.jpg,2.jpg and likewise.
                count++;
                String file = dir + count + ".jpg";
                File newfile = new File(file);
                try {
                    newfile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }

                outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);



                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");
            ImageSwitcher switcher = new ImageSwitcher(getApplicationContext());
            switcher.setImageURI(outputFileUri);


        }
    }
```

This is the closest i got. Camera launching and taking a photo. I am not sure i am assigning it right. It needs to be only one photo and i need the URI public so i can save it later to SQLite. For starter displaying will do. Any ideas? (the code is not mine, i am not that advanced in Android)
EDIT: Photos must be set on map markers so i need unique names so i can get them for the markers individually. It is also an option one marker to have several photos into horizontal slide. My point is that the code must be reusable.Also i have no idea what to add in OnResume() when the photo is already saved so it appear in the holder

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.fixxxer.mapapplication/com.example.fixxxer.mapapplication.MarkerInfo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Image holder? Place holder? Please name the component by it's name.

Comment: 'newdir.mkdirs();'. You are not checking the return value. So you do not know if the dir is created. Moreover you should first check if the dir already exists. If it exists then do not  call mkdirs().

Comment: @greenapps image holder, still don't get why the null pointer. Folder exists after test. File doesn't

Comment: You did not adapt your code though. And didn't you have null pointers at two occasions? Check if they are null before use. And don't use them if so.